# Social Plugin Comments failure on login

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

Plugin: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Hi... i'm try to use the `comments` plugin and it's showing the comments fine, but when an unregistered user try to login with his facebook account, the login form returns a message:

> Not Found
>
> Back to Facebook.

See the problem in the site: http://novosite.newvips.com.br... just click in an EVENT... (evento in portuguese)... and try to comment using your facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, this worked just fine for me to comment on your events when logged in, and it did the right thing to direct me to login flow when I was not logged in. Can you describe in detail the flow that is causing an issue for you?